# Documentation on creating tasks

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, tasks

I'm looking to integrate tasks into a plugin I'm building. Whilst I know that the Craft documentation shows the Tasks Service/Model properties/methods in the full class reference, I can't find anything online about best practices regarding using tasks in plugins. Has anyone come across any articles about creating your own tasks?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any articles or best practice documents.

There is a sample/simple [PowerNap](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/PowerNap/) plugin that shows the basics of creating and running a task as well as the [TaskService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TasksService) class reference documentation which you've already found.

Comment: One other headache I had when creating a task for a custom plugin - make sure you name the file/class for your task to be prefixed with the plugin name (which is a standard Craft convention). Something like `MyPlugin_BeAwesomeTask.php`.